# Why Safari is trying to Download web pages even thought I don't want that (iOS 13.3 - iPhone 8)

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

Sometimes When I use safari to look news, Its trying to Download instead of open normally, I see on screen a dialog box has Download button for ex: index.php. I searched for this problem, but found only similar problem on Mac's Safari, and other users advice Booting Safe Mode and make some steps. But on iPhone there is no option about it. I don't wanna recovery or reset all data, Is there any way to set defaults for safari on iPhone? And is there any information about this issue?

Comment: Do you have an example of a page that doesn't work?

Comment: for example Mynet.com or eskisozluk.com etc.  But abnormal situation is it sometimes happens not always. There aren't any sites that may be broken, everybody uses them. If sites have problems , we could see discussions and topics about them. I mean sites look normal. May vpn services cause it?

Comment: Try without the VPN & report back.

Comment: Which VPN are you using ? As suggested before try without it.

Comment: It looks normal nowadays. I used Kaspersky secure connection. Last week I passed to TrendMicro Mobile Security and it has vpn service that works like secure dns service, actually not complete vpn. But I haven't seen Download dialog last 4 days